# What creatures presumably killed the character Gor Koresh in the season 2 premier of The Mandalorian?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the first act of the second season of *Star Wars* TV series, *The Mandalorian*, Din Djarin and The Child go to visit a mob boss named Gor Koresh in order to get information about where he can find more of his kind (other Mandalorians).

Gor Koresh plays dirty and attempts to kill Din Djarin, but he and his thugs are no match. After the skirmish, Din takes Gor outside on the streets and ties him up upside down. He promises that Gor will not die by *his hand*, and demands the information, which Gor gives, but then Din leaves him there and creatures with glowing red eyes come out of the shadows and begin to attack Gor!!!!

What or whom are these creatures??

Comment: Why the down vote, if I may ask?

Comment: As of writing, I don't believe these have been identified - https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_red-eyed_quadruped

Comment: Ya, I was hoping maybe it might be answered in an interview or in the Disney Gallery: The Mandalorian (S2)...